# Playframework test. FakeRequest sent with empty body always (scala)

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been struggling several hours and every time I send a FakeRequest, it seems that the FakeApplication receives an empty body. However, if I try to run the play application and I send a normal request to localhost, everything works as expected, I receive the text I sent as a response.

[image]

Another test of the test that I have done is sending a custom response (not the same it receives) from the controller, like a string "a".

My test code looks like:

```
      val controller = app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[CreateRecordController])
  val js = Json.obj()
  val result = controller.apply().apply(
    FakeRequest(POST, "/api/v1/record/")
      .withHeaders(Headers(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json"))
      .withJsonBody(js)
  )

  val content = contentAsJson(result)

  info.apply(s"content was $content")
```

The last statement prints: "content was" and an html page saying: "For request 'POST /api/v1/record/' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@5fdfe8cf; line: 1, column: 0]]" -> So the content is empty.

My action handler in the controller is:

```
  def apply: Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>

          Future.successful(BadRequest(request.body).withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json"))

   }
```

Am I missing something?

Play version: 2.6.2

Comment: You probably have a BodyParser in your controller which is expecting a JSON and empty body is an invalid JSON technically hence the error response. Can you paste your Action handler from the Controller?

Comment: @saheb controller posted. As I explain in the question, sending a request to the corresponding uri with POST works as expected

Comment: Now after your edit. You are sending content type as `application/json` in your response and the body (`request.body.toString`) is not a valid JSON. Hence the error.

Comment: @saheb The example was not correct, I messed up with text and json types. It is as it should be now but it is still not working.

Comment: @saheb Ok, I have removed the .toString call, and it throws the same response.

Comment: print the value of js. Is it empty? or some invalid JSON? And you are using parse.text, use parse.json if your content-type is JSON

Comment: @saheb sry, I messed up again copying the code, parse.json is fixed in the post now. I've printed `js.toString` and the result is `{}`

Comment: I have been able to replicate the issue, working to figure out what's going on. Meanwhile I think you should replace Fake Application with GuiceApplicationBuilder https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Changes-to-play.api.test-Helpers

Comment: @saheb see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, give this a read first - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaEssentialAction

Controller

```
  def work = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(BadRequest(request.body).withHeaders((CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")))
  }
```

Test

```
class ApplicationSpec extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerTest with Injecting {
    "Application" should {
        "work" in {
          implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer
          val controller = new Application(inject[ControllerComponents])
          val body = Json.obj()
          val result = call(controller.work(), FakeRequest(POST, "/work").withHeaders((CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")).withJsonBody(body))
          contentAsJson(result) mustBe body
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also documented here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Unit-Testing-EssentialAction but not super clear on when this should be used

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if the content is passed to the FakeRequest at construction time it works as expected. What I've seen is that if I pass a JsValue as the body at construction time, the FakeRequest is of type FakeRequest[JsValue] which works fine. But if the method .withBodyAsJson is used, the type becomes FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson].  It may be a bug.